# React Invalid hook call: how to avoid a nested hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket, webrtc

How can I set up a connection inside `useEffect` and at the same time decorate that connection with a custom hook? Custom hooks are not allowed to run inside `useEffect` and `ref.current` is not permitted during rendering. What is the proper way to wrap a connection with a React-friendly interface?

I believe the right way to set up a `WebSocket` connection in React, is with a `useEffect` hook, along the lines of

```js
const connection = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
  connection.current = ws;

  return () => {
    ws.close();
    connection.current = null;
  }
}, [socketUrl]);
```

In a similar way I envisage creating a `RTCDataConnection`, which follows the same connection interface with `.send('...')` and `open`, `close`, `error` and `message` events.

I am looking for a way to provide a React-like interface to these connections. I was thinking something like the following custom `useConnection` hook, which takes a JavaScript connection object and in return provides two React state variables `lastMessage` and `readyState`, and a method `sendMessage`:

```
export function useConnection(connection) {
  const [lastMessage, setLastMessage] = useState(null);
  const [readyState, setReadyState] = useState(null);

  const onReadyStateChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      console.info(e);
      setReadyState(connection.readyState);
    },
    [setReadyState]
  );

  const onMessage = useCallback(
    ({ data }) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(data);
      setLastMessage(message);
    },
    [setLastMessage]
  );

  function sendMessage(message) {
    const msgJSON = JSON.stringify(message);
    connection.send(msgJSON);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    connection.addEventListener('open', onReadyStateChange);
    connection.addEventListener('close', onReadyStateChange);
    connection.addEventListener('error', onReadyStateChange);
    connection.addEventListener('message', onMessage);

    return () => {
      connection.removeEventListener('open', onReadyStateChange);
      connection.removeEventListener('close', onReadyStateChange);
      connection.removeEventListener('error', onReadyStateChange);
      connection.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
    };
  }, [connection]);

  return { lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage };
}
```

I can't find out, however, how to properly apply the hook to the connection.

- By [the rules of hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning), I can't call `useConnection` inside `useEffect`. It throws "Invalid hook call" at me.
- I can't reference `connection.current` outside the `useEffect` either, because that violates [the rules of `useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef): It is not allowed to access the `.current` property during rendering.

So my question is, how do I bring the connection and the hook together? Or should I use a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, i.e. call the hook

```js
const {lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage} = useConnection(something);
```

from inside `useEffect` because it is the only place where you have access to `something` so this is not possible.
hooks should be called in the body of your function component not conditionally and not inside a loop you can think of them like an import.

### solution:

create a state `connection` and use its value as `useConnection` function parameter

```js
const [connection, setConnection] = useState(null);
const { lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage } = useConnection(connection);
```

**Note:** you may need to make some extra work in your hook to handle `null` connection received because this will happen when the hook is called in the component first mount

Now from `useEffect` instead of call the hook, you just update `connection` state with the value you want to call your custom hook with i.e `something`.
 when the state is updated, the component re-renders and your hook function will be recalled if it receives a new value as parameter so when `connection` gets a new value, therefore it returns a new `{lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage}` values that you can have access to, in this new render

so if you want to use them directly inside your `useEffect` just after updating `connection` state, then this is not possible, however, you can still create another `useEffect` that fire each time `connection` is updated, so after the component re-renders by updating `connection` in the first `useEffect` now since it is a new render you will have access to the new values returned by the hook in the second `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 // continue your logic here
 if(connection){
   sendMessage("new msg")
 }
},[connection?.id])
```

The function should work with the expected `connection` object when executes `connection.send(msgJSON)` since it is a new instance that receives the expected `connection`
here I added `connection?.id` as dependency instead of `connection` because we want to avoid including object, such a key should exist in the `connection` object

**Note** that `useEffect` hook is firing each time values in its dependency array are updated but also in the component first mount.

Comment: So if I get it right, what you're proposing is to replace `useRef` by `useState`, then the two hooks `useState` and `useConnection` can live next to each other happily. That makes it a workaround for the `useRef` rule that could certainly work. My only concern is I've nowhere seen people put WebSocket in a state variable. Is that an accepted thing to do? Why do others not do that? Perhaps can you clarify this choice a little in the answer?

Comment: here I try to give a solution to how you can make it work with a custom hook just to answer the question and explain why you can't do what you want to do and yes I used to store the socket object in a context and call it from different components in fact it is an object so you can store it in a state I don't see anything wrong with that, now about it is a workaround for ref, the difference is that when you update the ref the component won't rerender and the custom hook will not be recalled when your ref is receiving a new socket object however when you use a state, it will do

Comment: it is true that the hook will be called on each render since we pass an object as a parameter to it (that what the implementation requires) but hopefully the code inside the second `useEffect` will run only when `connection?.id` changes so that's ok in fact this is why you don't want to include `connectyion` in the dependency array to avoid firing the second `useEffect` on each render

Comment: That's clever, the state causing a re-render where the ref doesn't. I don't quite like adding extra renders but it is definitely a solution that works. (Also need to add the `connection.id` on the `useCallback` by the way, but verified working solution).

Comment: in terms of renders you are right if you can manage to do all the work from inside the effect, this will save you one render but it is not possible at least with this solution of using a custom hook to manage that

Answer (score 0):

What you would probably want is to call your hook at the top level of your component and then use it's returned parts inside the `useEffect()`

```
const {lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage} = useConnection(connection);

useEffect(() => {
    sendMessage("Hi");
}, [sendMessage]);
```

Your approach looks fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I redesigned `useConnection` to take a factory function rather than the connection object directly. Not only does this circumvent the `useRef`, it also makes the calling code much cleaner (and more aligned with [the React devs views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802751/2290493)). This is now how to use the `useConnection` hook:

```js
const { lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage } = useConnection(
  () => new WebSocket(socketUrl)
);
```

That's all. (You can wrap that in a `useMemo` if `socketUrl` is variable.) `useConnection` now looks like this:

```js
/**
 * Provides a React-friendly interface around a JS connection.
 * It exposes two state variables: lastMessage and readyState,
 * and one method sendMessage(json).
 * factory is a factory function that creates a new connection.
 */
export function useConnection(factory) {
  const empty = () => {};

  let sendMessage = empty;
  const [lastMessage, setLastMessage] = useState('');
  const [readyState, setReadyState] = useState(null);

  // The two event handlers do not depend on the connection
  // and are therefore declared outside `useEffect`.

  const handleMessage = ({ data }) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(data);
    setLastMessage(message);
  };

  const handleReadyStateChange = (e) => {
    console.debug(e);
    setReadyState(e.target.readyState);
  };

  // The effect, setting up and tearing down the connection,
  // depends on the factory function.

  useEffect(() => {
    let conn = null;

    const connect = () => {
      console.log('✅ Connecting...');
      conn = factory();
      conn.addEventListener('open', handleReadyStateChange);
      conn.addEventListener('close', handleReadyStateChange);
      conn.addEventListener('error', handleReadyStateChange);
      conn.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
      sendMessage = send;
    };

    const disconnect = () => {
      console.log('❌ Disconnecting...');
      conn.removeEventListener('open', handleReadyStateChange);
      conn.removeEventListener('close', handleReadyStateChange);
      conn.removeEventListener('error', handleReadyStateChange);
      conn.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
      // Avoid an error message in the console saying:
      // "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."
      if (conn.readyState === 1) {
        conn.close();
      }
      sendMessage = empty;
      setReadyState(conn.readyState);
      conn = null;
    };

    // The send method does depend on the connection and so
    // is declared inside `useEffect`.

    const send = (message) => {
      if (conn) {
        const msgJSON = JSON.stringify(message);
        conn.send(msgJSON);
      }
    };

    connect();

    return disconnect;
  }, [factory]);

  return { lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage };
}
```

The accepted answer being closer to the original question, I will leave that as is.